# Curl via Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, post

Hi  I am having major problems and its driving me mad  - 3 x php developers all say the code is right, but it still doesnt 'post' the data from the form into the seperate crm website.  - which is clearly the whole point !  when someone submits a form i want their record to be created in my crm system

I have a wordpress site using formidable Pro form,  that i want to send data to my crm system.

I think there is a problem with how wordpress sends or tells curl to work,  - bit i'm not a tech person so my knowledge and understanding is a bit thin.  Right now - i believe the code gets a 200 code which means its all ok  - trouble is  there is no data at the other end in my crm system - could anyone point out whats wrong ?

( ps posting url changed just so i dont break privacy rules on here , pps  i have echoed out // a lot of the items  just to see if i can get it to even just send the surname through )

The numbers in boxes are how formidable pro sees the data its collected   ie  surname is  [861]    is it the brackets that are causing an issue  or is it the way the curl is dending the data - or is it wordpress !?

pps  using 'code snippets' a php plugin for wordpress to enable the php code

code.........

add_action('frm_after_create_entry', 'after_entry_created', 30, 2);
function after_entry_created($entry_id, $form_id){

```
if($form_id == 21){

$url = 'https://secure4.mline.co.uk/DavidFarrell/php/NewMortgage.php';
$fields = array(
    //Mandatory fields go here:
    'MortgageMode' => urlencode(1), // OR 'CommercialMode => urlendcode(1), for CommercialKeeper
    'StagePK' => urlencode(25),
    'AdvisorPK' => urlencode(1),
    'Surname1'=>urlencode($_POST['[861]']),

    //Other fields to post into go here:

//Mortgage Details
//'LenderPK'=>urlencode(1),
//'InterestRateTypePK'=>urlencode(2),
//'Rate'=>urlencode(3.45),
//'DealTerm'=>urlencode(5),
//'Term'=>urlencode(25),
//'ActionPK'=>urlencode(11),
//'ActionText'=>urlencode($_POST['Notes']),

//Applicant Details
//'Forename1'=>urlencode($_POST['859']),
//'Email1'=>urlencode($_POST['Emailaddress'][864]),
//'DayPhone'=>urlencode($_POST['[867]']),
//'MobilePhone'=>urlencode($_POST['MobilePhone1'][866]),
//'Forename2'=>urlencode($_POST['[880]']),
//'Surname2'=>urlencode($_POST['[882]']),
//'MidNameApp1'=>urlencode($_POST['[860]']),
//'MidNameApp2'=>urlencode($_POST['[881]']),

    //Submit is also mandatory and typically is placed at the end of your array
'submit'=>true
);

// Loops through the $fields array and results in a string variable called $fields_string which is a URL friendly string
foreach($fields as $key => $value)
{
    //adds the key which is the eKeeper field followed by an '=', followed by and ampersand (&)
    $fields_string.=$key.'='.$value.'&';       
}
//trims any whitespace and cleans up the $fields_string variable
rtrim($fields_string,'&amp;');

// Initialises a cURL connection
$ch = curl_init();


//Sets the URL to post into using the $url variable that was initialised earlier
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
// Sets the number of fields to be passed, this is achieved by using the count() function to count the elements in the $fields array.
//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
// Sets the string that contains the eKeeper fields and their values ($fields_string)
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
// Sets the return transfer option to true so that the return value after execution
  // curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
  curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);

// Executes the curl session. must not be done until after the session has been initilised and the relevant curl options have been set.
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// Closes the connection/curl session
curl_close($ch);
}
```

}

Comment: Do you get any information looking at curl infos/errors?
$info = curl_getinfo($ch); $error = curl_error($ch);

Comment: Possible cause ; `curl`has problems with your `https certificate`. Try adding the option `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` to `0` and see if that makes any difference? (http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php). Also check your `curl_getinfo` for errors.

Answer (score 0):

well, this part is definitely wrong

```
foreach($fields as $key => $value)
{
    //adds the key which is the eKeeper field followed by an '=', followed by and ampersand (&)
    $fields_string.=$key.'='.$value.'&';       
}
//trims any whitespace and cleans up the $fields_string variable
rtrim($fields_string,'&amp;');
```

neither the key nor the value is url encoded, so if the key or value contains ÆØÅ or spaces or & or a bunch of other characters, they will be encoded wrong. also that rtrim is NOT how you trim an urlencoded string at all, no idea how that got past 3 devs.

correcting that would be

```
foreach($fields as $key => $value)
{
    $fields_string.=urlencode($key).'='.urlencode($value).'&';       
}
if(!empty($fields)){
    //remove the last &
    $fields_string=substr($fields_string,0,-1);
}
```

but luckily, PHP has a built-in function for making `x-www-form-urlencoded`-formatted strings called `http_build_query`, so the entire code could be replaced with:

```
$fields_string.=http_build_query($fields);
```

which would basically do that entire encoding loop for you. other than that, you have a bunch of undefined variables, but i guess those are mostly just removed code (you state that you removed a bunch before posting it here), but if not, setting `error_reporting=E_ALL` in php.ini would notice you of of most of them (but not arrays, because php is stupid, arrays are implicitly created without warning when pushed to)

but, as i have said so many times before, when debugging curl requests, always enable `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` - do that, and post the CURLOPT_VERBOSE stderr log in your main post, with that log, we may be of more assistance